# PHP can't decode JSON encoded with json_encode

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, geojson

I'm using this code to encode **large**(cca 60mb) geojson before storing it to database:

```
// controller
public function importZones () {

    ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    ini_set("precision", -1);
    ini_set("serialize_precision", -1);

    $this->load->helper('url');

    $filePath = base_url('assets/zones/zone.geojson');

    $jsonStream = \JsonMachine\JsonMachine::fromFile($filePath, "/features");
    $this->PolygonModel->import($jsonStream)

}
// model
public function import ($jsonStream) {
    $import = [];
    foreach ($jsonStream as $name => $data) {
        // $coordinates is nested indexed array with possibly thousands of elements
        $coordinates = json_encode($data['geometry']['coordinates']); 
        $import['baz'][] = [
             'foo' => 'bar',
             'coordinates' => $coordinates
        ];
    }
    echo json_last_error_msg(); // gives no errors 

   // insert encoded data to db...
}
```

I'm using this code to decode the string after selecting it from database

```
// decode and fix json if corrupted (huge arrays..)

private function decodeZoneCoords ($coordsJson) {

 $decoded = json_decode($coordsJson, true);

 if (!$decoded) {
    // some fixes I've found online
    $json = $coordsJson;
    // before removing cntrl I get the  “Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded” error
    $json = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $coordsJson);
    $json = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $coordsJson);
    $json = mb_convert_encoding($json, "UTF-8");
    $json = ltrim($json . '"' . "]", '1');
    if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($json), 'efbbbf')) {
       $json = substr($json, 3);
    }

    $decoded = json_decode($json, true);
    if (!$decoded) {
        $json = rtrim($json, ',"]') . '"]';
        $decoded = json_decode($json, true);
    }
 } 

 if (!$decoded) {
  echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( json_decode($json, true) ); // null
  echo "</pre>";
  echo json_last_error_msg(); // "syntax error"
  echo 'JSON ERROR(from zone):';
  echo '<hr>';
  echo $json;
  die();
}

 return $decoded;
```

}

When I try to decode it I get syntax error message from json_last_error_msg function and json_encode function returns null.

Edit:

I just realized that var_dumping the string gives me this: **string(65535) "...**

Could it be that MySql truncates my JSON after that lenght even though im using the **text** field to store encoded string?

Comment: 65535 is the exact length of a text field in MySQL. If your json string is longer than that, use mediumtext or longtext. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-syntax.html

Comment: Thanks for tip, that was my problem, part of json was being cut out because it was too long. If you submit that as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @failedCoder or even better: MySQL has a specific data type for JSON data. Rather than using `text`, `mediumtext` or `longtext` you should be using JSON for the data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

65535 is the exact length of a [text field in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-syntax.html). If your json string is longer than that, use mediumtext (16,777,215 characters) or longtext (4,294,967,295 characters).

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing JSON data in your MySQL database, you shouldn't use neither `text` nor `mediumtext` nor `longtext`. 
There's a `JSON` datatype created specifically for storing JSON data in your tables.

I'd suggest altering your table and changing the column type to JSON instead of any text type.